# Languages to represent ellipse geometry (WKB/WKT)

Tags: geometry, well-known-text, geometry-conversion, well-known-binary

I am new to the idea of representing vector geometries in a text markup language. I am looking into different representations for geometries consisting of smooth curves and three dimensional objects, for example, an ellipse or a 3 dimensional wedge.

I have been looking into WKB as a possibility as it has the capability to represent a smooth continuous curve or surface, as shown in the geometry types of the wiki here:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry#Well-known_binary

However, I have not been able to find any examples of how to represent say an ellipse or curve once the endian and type have been established. I have seen examples of how to represent three dimensional shapes such as the wedge mentioned above in WKB.

My question is twofold: how would I represent curves and surfaces in WKB? And secondarily, is this a standard (or common) way to represent such geometries? WKT doesn’t appear to lend itself to geometries beyond polyhedral approximations and I am not aware of any language more suited to these types of geometries.

Comment: WKT and WKB encodings of curved geometries are usually based on an ISO standard that unfortunately is not free. There is an archived draft document in https://web.archive.org/web/20071212154300/http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N1101-1150/32N1107-WD13249-3--spatial.pdf. See if there is something interesting.